# What does "10 years sober" mean?

Tags: meaning, expressions

Here is the full sentence:

> You’re from Orinda, your father’s in commercial real estate and your mother’s 10 years
>   sober.

Comment: According to my careful calculations, I've been sober for 48 years, drunk for around five.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hasn't had a (alcoholic) drink for ten years - presumably was an alcoholic and is now clean.

In the context presumably intended as a slur on the sort of person whose parents sell real estate and are recovering alcholics!

Comment: Speaking on the context of the sentence, I read it as more of a commentary on the town of Orinda and the types of people that live there.

Comment: Sober can also refer to being intoxicant-free in a more general sense (such as drug-free). Though I do agree that "drug-free" is more common in that context, I have seen sober refer to non-alcoholic intoxicants.

Answer (score 2):

To be "10 years sober" means that the person has not used alcohol for 10 years.

You can also say, "I've been *clean* for 10 years" to mean you haven't used drugs in 10 years.

People often use the two terms together, "clean and sober for 10 years."

Answer (score 1):

In the reported sentence *sober* means "not affected by alcohol; not drunk."

Other meanings of *sober* are:

- serious, sensible, and solemn: *a sober view of life*
- free from alcoholism; not habitually drinking alcohol
- muted in color: *a sober gray suit*

Comment: Although the primary meaning of *sober* is indeed not drunk (and so allows for the possibility of one's having consumed a small amount of alcohol), it is practically never used in that sense in the formulations like 'has been sober for ___ months/years'; they are reserved for people who were alcoholics in the past and have been abstaining from alcohol **altogether**, in order to avoid relapsing into alcoholism.